# laravel 5.6 sending mail to 10,000+ subscribers when a new post is added

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

Hi i am new to laravel and trying to implement a functionality when a post is added a mail to all the subscribers of the website(more than 10K) is sent. what is the best way to implement it, my server capability is sending 100 mails/ hour.

Comment: Maybe you should look to implement https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues

Answer (score 0):

Use [Mandrill](https://mandrill.com/) or [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) and send them in batches.

Use a service like [Mailchimp](https://mailchimp.com/), [Campaign Monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/), or [Sendy](https://sendy.co/) if you want to host your own system.

Comment: i want some free or open source solution

Comment: free solution in development stage or production ?

Comment: free solution in production

Answer (score 0):

Queue it in Amazon SQS and send as batches. Laravel has all built in.

[enter link description here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues)

> FREE TIER: Each month, Amazon SQS customers pay no charges for the
>   first 1,000,000 Amazon SQS Requests

Comment: amazon is asking for credit card when making account

Comment: Yes it is to verify you identity. They don't charge for SQS unto 1M. SQS is in their always free tier.Please check https://aws.amazon.com/free/?awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=categories%23alwaysfree